# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "&p"

Tags: java

```
public static String sanitizeInput(String query){
    try {
        String decodedString = null;
        if (query.contains(Constants.Strings.DECODE_PERCENT) || query.contains(Constants.Strings.PLUS)) {
            decodedString = URLDecoder.decode(query, Constants.Encoding.UTF8);
            if (query.equals(URLEncoder.encode(decodedString, Constants.Encoding.UTF8))) {
                return query;
            }
        }
        return query.contains(Constants.Strings.PERCENT) ?  URLEncoder.encode(query, Constants.Encoding.UTF8) : query ;
    }  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while encoding query", e);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Getting this error when I use % in the search input .

My logic says if %25 format is already present in the string then it is already in encoded format . Then I apply decode. If the query string only has % then it is already in decoded format so we avoid decoding.

Comment: Pleaseprovide the input querystring and which line exactly this exception happens?

Comment: query = "blue%"

Comment: return query.contains(Constants.Strings.PERCENT) ?  URLEncoder.encode(query, Constants.Encoding.UTF8) : query ; //error comes up in this line

Comment: if this query is coming directly from a request, you have to determine if it's going to be decoded always or encoded always. I'm not sure why you are running into a situation where the query can be both? in any case, decoding a string that's already been decoded is harmless (unless the decoded string contains %, in that case decoding twice can produce different results).